# Printing a page with Ctrl+P makes some words bold

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I am working on a project where I need to print the document via window.print() function. When I try to print the page, it makes small L (l) and small I (i) bold. And they both looks same. It is hard to differentiate between them.

[image]

```
@media print {
*,*:before,*:after {color: #000 !important;text-shadow: none !important;background: transparent !important;    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;box-shadow: none !important;}
a,a:visited {text-decoration: underline;}
a[href]:after {content: " (" attr(href) ")";}
abbr[title]:after {content: " (" attr(title) ")";}
a[href^="#"]:after,a[href^="javascript:"]:after {content: "";}
/** Don't show links for images, or javascript/internal links   */
.ir a:after,a[href^="javascript:"]:after,a[href^="#"]:after {content: "";}
pre,blockquote {border: 1px solid #999;page-break-inside: avoid;}
thead {display: table-header-group; /* h5bp.com/t */  }
tr,img {page-break-inside: avoid;}
img {max-width: 100% !important;}
@page {margin: 0.5cm;}
p,h2,h3 {orphans: 3;widows: 3;}
h2,h3 {page-break-after: avoid;}
.print_hide{display:none !important;}
.a_page_b{page-break-inside: avoid;}
```

}

Comment: Are you printing from a webpage if so have you used any media quires in that webpage for printing ?

Comment: Yes, I used media quires.

Comment: Does the Webpage show the "I" and "L" Properly or is it the same case in the webpage too ?

Comment: Webpage show properly... even in the print view, it shows properly. But it is happening after printing.

Comment: can you share the print meadi query or the css file

Comment: are you using any external font styles ?

Comment: full print code can't be paste once. So, please see this in edited post

Comment: is this text from a print preview ? or a printed text ? (could be a zoom on the print preview)

Comment: Nope, 100% zoom and it is a screenshot from the pdf.

Comment: Try to take another font-family and another printer.